# Change url using .htaccess for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Hi I need to achieve the following url change using .htaccess for my wordpress site.

I have this link http://www.johnjhoward.com/search-by-mls/

so what I want to do is to rewrite the URI in to this kind of format 
http://www.johnjhoward.com/listings/listings #/address

I want to add the mls# and the address of my mls into my URI. I don't know where to start and how to do it.

**`.htaccess`**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /search-by-mls/(.*) /listings/listings $1
```

[Htaccess Redirect Generator](http://www.webconfs.com/htaccess-redirect-generator.php)